# Logo and image responsiveness

Tags: html, css

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gu7b3fbs/

I'm looking to position the image in the center, and the "Go to the main website" to the ultimate right higher than the picture, while keeping responsivness. However when re-sizing the window, "Go to the main website" should pass above the image. Any help?

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav">
                <ul>
                        <li class="a"><a href="">Go to the main website</a> </li>

                </ul>
            <div class="clear"> </div>
           </div>
            <div class="clear"> </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,dl,dt,dd,ol,nav ul,nav li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;font:inherit;vertical-align:baseline;}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {display: block;}
ol,ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
blockquote,q{quotes:none;}
blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
/* start editing from here */
a{text-decoration:none;}
.txt-rt{text-align:right;}/* text align right */
.txt-lt{text-align:left;}/* text align left */
.txt-center{text-align:center;}/* text align center */
.float-rt{float:right;}/* float right */
.float-lt{float:left;}/* float left */
.clear{clear:both;}/* clear float */
.pos-relative{position:relative;}/* Position Relative */
.pos-absolute{position:absolute;}/* Position Absolute */
.vertical-base{ vertical-align:baseline;}/* vertical align baseline */
.vertical-top{  vertical-align:top;}/* vertical align top */
.underline{ padding-bottom:5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; margin:0 0 20px 0;}/* Add 5px bottom padding and a underline */
nav.vertical ul li{ display:block;}/* vertical menu */
nav.horizontal ul li{   display: inline-block;}/* horizontal menu */
img{max-width:100%;}
/*end reset*/
body {
  background: url('../images/bg.jpg') repeat;
}
.wrap {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

.header {
    background: white;
    border-bottom: 13px solid white;
    border-top: 13px solid white;
    margin-top: 0em;
}
.logo
{
    float: left;
  padding-top: 21px;
}
.nav
{
    float: right;
    width: 47%;

}
.nav ul li
{
    float:left;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.65);
}
.nav ul li.a
{
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.65);

}
.nav ul li a
{
    font-size: 1.0em;
    color:#5F6A72;
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
  display: block;
     -webkit-transition: 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.5s linear;
    transition: 0.5s linear;
    padding: 3px 30px;

}
.nav ul li a:hover
{

}
```

This is the position:
[image]

Comment: question in unclear somewhere.Please make it clear for better understanding.

Comment: and if you want logo in center then why you gave float:left to logo class?

Comment: @Leothelion man  i built my first website that turned out to be a total disaster in terms of responsiveness. Now i got a template to keep responsiveness so i'm learning. And i updated the post with an image of the positioning.

Comment: if you are learning then go for bootstrap 3 and media queries..media query will be more easy.

Comment: @Leothelion yes everybody told me the same thing, but i'm on a deadline

Comment: ok then give me your live site example..will solve your issue..

Comment: @Leothelion can we open a chat conv to show you the original website i built

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82042/discussion-between-mikeb-and-leo-the-lion).

Answer (score 0):

is this the desired output?

```
 .logo{
      padding-top: 21px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      //float: left; //remove this
 }
```